# Default input device sox

Tags: audio, sox, microphone

I'm trying to configure `sox` to use a webcam that I just ordered. I've confirmed that the mic works through the GUI.

I ran `arecord -l` and found that the card, device numbers are 1 and 0, respectively.

I'm using `sox` through a Node.js library that runs it with the following arguments:

```
this.cmdArgs = [
    '-q',
    '-b','16',
    '-d','-t','flac','-',
    'rate','16000','channels','1',
    'silence','1','0.1', '0.1%','1','1.0', '0.1%'
];
```

However, I all I hear from the mic is really loud static.

I've tried setting `AUDIODEV` to `hw:1,0` and `AUDIODRIVER` to `alsa` but I have the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: You may have the right device, but the wrong format, so that the audio bits are getting scrambled. If so, you'd probably be able to hear changes in the "static" with changes in the audio input.